# Does more than 1000 redirects in IIS 7.5 affect site response time and or performance

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I hope the title does already explain my question. We have a website with more than 1000 static urls defined in a rewritemap (iis 7.5 rewrite module). If this number still increases, will this affect the site response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,000 entries should not be a problem for a RewriteMap, it is implemented as a Hash table that should perform extremely well. What can be more impactful is the complexity of the rule that you use, so if you do a very complex RegEx or something like that, it could impact. In particular if what you use are things like PHP or ASP, the performance impact will be completely negligible in comparison to the actual dynamic content handlers.

But having said all that, the best thing is always to measure your specific case.